Why does Visual Studio reference an incorrect package
The project ParentMutator.Fody references a NuGet package FodyHelper.
The project ParentMutator.Tests references the project ParentMutator.Fody.
However, the dependency graph of ParentMutator.Tests shows that ParentMutator.Fody references the package Fody instead of FodyHelper.
Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

EDIT:
I still do not know the reason, but I found a solution.
Move all the projects out of the src and test folders, and the bug will be gone.
Here is my current solution structure:
ParentMutator.sln
├── src
│   ├── ParentMutator
│   └── ParentMutator.Fody
└── test
    ├── ParentMutator.Tests
    └── TestAssemblies
        ├── ChildDefinitions
        ├── NewParentDefinitions
        └── OriginalParentDefinitions

Here is the solution structure that I have changed:
ParentMutator.sln
├── ParentMutator
├── ParentMutator.Fody
├── ParentMutator.Tests
└── TestAssemblies
    ├── ChildDefinitions
    ├── NewParentDefinitions
    └── OriginalParentDefinitions

This link is a GIF that shows the process.

I did a quick test in VS2022 17.12.3 , unfortunately, i can't reproduce this issue. Please check my test result: https://i.sstatic.net/IUwapRWk.png.
Please check the following points:
1.What's the detailed version of your Visual Studio 2022?
2. Does this issue occur to all projects or specific project, you create a new project A and B and do steps above to narrow down the issue.
3.If you reference a new nuget package, e.g(Newtonsoft.Json),will it show wrong package?
4.Besides, you can repair your VS from VS Installer and then rebuild your project to see if the issue persists.

@DouXu-MSFT Thank you for your reply. I think you might not be able to reproduce this issue on your PC. It could be a problem related to the local environment. I encountered this situation a long time ago, and it reappeared after I upgraded Windows 11 to version 24H2 (though this may not be the cause).
I have tried many times to reproduce the issue but cannot consistently do so. However, I have found a way to fix it. I’ve updated my question and added a GIF to demonstrate the process.

I have cloned your code and did a test again, it shows well. As you said, it may be specific to your local environment. I would suggest you make sure that all the windows patches have been installed. then repair your VS or update to the latest version.
